# person who's too eager to ascribe malicious intent

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the word (formal or slang) or expression to describe a person who customarily and too easily ascribes bad motives to other people's behavior that could also be explained differently?

E.g. I would like to say:

> to a sufficiently X person, that thing could be interpreted as such and
>   such..." or "if I were an X, I would think that...

Comment: It sounds like *pessimistic* or *paranoid* to me.

Comment: related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor

Comment: Arguably, "normal". :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cynical,

> believing that people are motivated purely by self-interest; distrustful of human sincerity or integrity.

Apprehensive,

> anxious or fearful that something bad or unpleasant will happen.

The person may actually just be narrow-minded,

> not willing to listen to or tolerate other people's views; **prejudiced**.

Or biased, discriminatory, etc the list goes on for intentional suspicion.

I think such people are prone to projecting themselves (experience, history or childhood) unto others and hence, their thinking is always similar (in this case, ascribing people's motive as bad).

Answer (score 8):

Idiomatically, one word that could be used in such contexts is...

> [*"An **uncharitable** person might think [that malicious intent was a factor]"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20first%20100%20results%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22an%20uncharitable%20person%20might%20think%22&tbm=bks)

Answer (score 6):

That person could be described in a semi-slang way as [paranoid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paranoid) if the evil plotting and malicious activity is directed at them.

Comment: That's the thing, I was looking for a word that can be applied to a third-party observer.

Answer (score 4):

The word I would use is *suspicious*.

Comment: Shame this has so few upvotes, it seems to me it is the only word that describes this perfectly.

Comment: @ Vality Thanks. It might get more votes if I expended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A person who is abnormally suspicious is **[querulent](http://medicine.academic.ru/41572/querulent)**

> Denoting one who is ever suspicious, always opposing any suggestion,
>   complaining of ill treatment and of being slighted or misunderstood,
>   easily enraged, and dissatisfied; characteristic of paranoid
>   personalities.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the person has a very *sinister* outlook.

Answer (score -1):

*See evil everywhere* or *see the bad everywhere*.

> *An impure person [sees evil everywhere](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=l1jdWfnCROsC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=%22sees+evil+everywhere%22&source=bl&ots=c6f-LUFu16&sig=Tj1P3uj5Aa_kdeD3QV3s51QmokM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=zbt_U46bOaH00gWp34DoAw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22sees%20evil%20everywhere%22&f=false) and takes pleasure in the fact.*
>
> *Are you one of those negative people that [sees the bad everywhere](http://www.city-data.com/forum/alabama/986339-why-does-everyone-give-alabama-similar-11.html) you go?*