# Adjective to describe someone who thinks everyone is driven by self-interest

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term to describe a person who thinks that everyone is driven by personal interest rather than by philanthropy or charity; someone who is pessimistic about people's intent (whether they're honest or the opposite).

Comment: Neoclassical *economist*.

Comment: Ethically [blinkered](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20blinkered)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [person who's too eager to ascribe malicious intent](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172607/person-whos-too-eager-to-ascribe-malicious-intent)

Answer (score 4):

***Cynic***: "a person who believes that people are motivated purely by self-interest rather than acting for honorable or unselfish reasons" ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+cynic&sourceid=silk&ie=UTF-8)).

The adjective is ***cynical***.

Also, ***psychological egoist***: someone who believes "that humans are always motivated by self-interest, even in what seem to be acts of altruism" ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_egoism)).